# Семантика слова мольба

Tags: грамотная-речь, литература, стилистическая-сочетаемость

Обязательно ли слово "мольба" означает "прошение"?  Суть в том, что можно ли сказать так:"Будут просить в мольба Хранителя мироздания..."?

Answer (score 1):

Из словаря:

**МОЛЬБА**,  ж. Горячая, страстная **просьба**. Говорить с мольбой. М. во взгляде, в голосе. М. о помиловании, о пощаде. **Обращать свои мольбы к Богу.**

Можно написать так: **Будут обращаться в мольбах своих к Хранителю мироздания...**

Важно не употреблять однокоренные  глаголы: молить — мольба, просить — просьба, иначе это будет считаться стилистической погрешностью.

Comment: Это стихотворение, "обращаться" не подойдёт.

Comment: "Донимать в мольбах"- на ваш взгляд, нормально?

Comment: Нет, у глагола "донять" отрицательный смысл (Разг. Вывести из терпения, из равновесия, не давая покоя).